# Creating a bootstrap Dockerfile that automatically exposes files to the host operating system

Tags: github, automation, docker, boot2docker, dockerhub

I'm trying to create a bootstrap Dockerfile for web development.

I would like any containers to allow for access of my code from within and also from the host operating system (Mac OS X).

I cannot tell from the Docker reference what is the best way of automating this process.

Answer (score 1):

Use a volume that mounts the code on the host into the container e.g:

`docker run -d -v /Users/me/code:/code IMAGE`

You should now find the `/Users/me/code` is accessible at `/code` in the container. The boot2docker VM has shared your home directory, so there should be no problem mounting a volume from there.

Refer to the official docs for more information: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/